# How to use Linq/Lambda with ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, lambda

I have the following code that simply loops looking for a condition and places all matches into a new collection:

```
ObservableCollection<Device> allDevices = GetAllDevices();
ObservableCollection<Device> matchingDevices = new ObservableCollection<Device>();
foreach (Device device in allDevices )
{
    if (device.ID != 5)
        matchingDevices .Add(device);
}
```

Pretty simple.  I tried to convert this into a Lambda statement in conjunction with Linq extention methods, but it's failing:

```
var matchingDevices = (ObservableCollection<Device>)allDevices.Where(d => d.ID != 5);
```

This fails because it can't do the cast.  I tried appending .ToList(), but same problem occurred.  It sounds like this should be simple, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var matchingDevices = 
     new ObservableCollection<Device>(allDevices.Where(d => d.ID != 5));
```

ObservableCollection has a constructor that takes an IEnumerable and that's what your Where clause is giving you.